# How can I benchmark a condor HPC cluster using LINPACK?

Tags: benchmarking, cluster-computing, hpc, atlas, condor

I have an HPC cluster using condor as a cluster middleware the OS is CentOS on all the machine and I installed MPICH2. How can I benchmark the system to get the maximum Gflops? I installed linpack and atlas library but I did not find information in how to use them in condor.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the HPL benchmark is used, see http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/ .

This is what is currently being used to compose the Top500 list of supercomputers as well.

Comment: Will this work for the normal computers having condor ?

Comment: As long as you can provide the necessary dependencies (MPI, LAPACK, etc.), you should be fine.